# chart.js switch x/y axis on line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Let's say I have a line chart like this: https://jsfiddle.net/13fyhL4j/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var yLabels = [0, 2, 3, 6, 7];
var xLabels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: xLabels,
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Line',
                data: yLabels,
                fill: false,                
            }
        ]
    },
    options:{
        scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'x label'
                        },

                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'y label'
                        },

                    }]
                }
    }
});
```

Here x axis has category scale and y axis has linear scale. I need to swap axis, however, I cannot find how to make x axis linear and y axis category.

[Image explaning situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44JcD.png)

It is necessary to change not only the axis values, but also the chart itself.

Comment: Check this example that I made to another question: https://jsfiddle.net/4th6rbcw/3/
It's not perfect but it might help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find anything that indicates you can do it with a line graph, but you could do it with scatter. The first step is abstracting away the axis properties from `xAxes` and `yAxes`:

```
const xAxis = [{
    /*type: 'time', time: { displayFormats: {} }, whatever*/
}];

const revenueAxis = [{
    /*scaleLabel: {}, ticks: {}, whatever*/
}];
```

Then you decide which data set to put on which axis by whatever condition you define:

```
let swapAxes = true;
const xValues = [1,2,3,4,5];
const yValues = [5,4,3,2,1];
let data = [];

const zipper = (a, b) => {
    for (let i of a) data.push({x: a[i-1], y: b[i-1]});
    return data;
}

data = condition ? zipper(yValues , xValues) : zipper(xValues, yValues );
```

You'll notice that each action in `zipper()` pushes an object with the values `x` and `y` onto an array. This is how chartjs is set up to receive data (an array of objects containing the values `x` and `y`), so make sure you follow that pattern.

Now set the axes:

```
const options = {
    /*Whatever options you have*/,
    scales: {
        xAxes: condition ? yAxis : xAxis,
        yAxes: condition ? xAxis : yAxis
    }
}
```

Now if you put that in your code, all you have to do is toggle `condition` to switch axes.